# Custom linked list in java iterator not able to iterate over the entire list

Tags: java, iterator

I have created a linked list in java, the issue is with

```
    public void add(T data)
```

when I try to add some thing at the end of the list, "null" is getting added to the end of the list. I think there is some problem with my iterator which is not able to find the last node.
Plz help.

```
public class LinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    private Node<T> head;
    /**
     * Default constructor
     * 
     * @param head
     */
    public LinkedList() {
        super();
        this.head = new Node<T>(null);
    }
    /**
     * Inserts a new node at the beginning of this list.
     */
    public void addFirst(T data) {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data, head);
        head = newNode;
    }
    public void add(T data) {
        Node<T> tempNpde = head;
        while (tempNpde.next != null) {
            tempNpde = tempNpde.next;
        }
        tempNpde.next = new Node<T>(data, null);
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param head
     * @return
     */
    public T getNode() {
        return head.data;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new ListIterator<T>();
    }
    public class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        private Node<T> currentNode;
        /**
         * @param currentNode
         */
        public ListIterator() {
            super();
            this.currentNode = (Node<T>) head;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (currentNode != null && currentNode.next != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        @Override
        public T next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            T node = currentNode.data;
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
            return node;
        }
        @Override
        public void remove() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
    // Same as using struct in C
    private static class Node<T> {
        private T data;
        private Node<T> next;
        /**
         * @param data
         * @param next
         */
        public Node(T data, Node<T> next) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
        /**
         * @param next
         */
        public Node(Node<T> next) {
            super();
            this.data = null;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.addFirst("aaaa");
        list.addFirst("bbbb");
        list.add("dddd");
        Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was already said, the biggest issue was that your `next()` wasn't doing what you thought it was... try this:

```
public class LinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    private Node<T> head;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     *
     * @param head
     */
    public LinkedList() {
        super();
        this.head = null;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a new node at the beginning of this list.
     */
    public void addFirst(T data) {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data, head);
        head = newNode;
    }

    public void add(T data) {

        if ( head == null )
        {
            head = new Node<T>(data, null);
            return;
        }

        Node<T> tempNode = head;
        while (tempNode.next != null) {
            tempNode = tempNode.next;
        }
        tempNode.next = new Node<T>(data, null);
    }

    /**
     * @param head
     * @return
     */
    public T getNode() {
        return head.data;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new ListIterator<T>();
    }

    public class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        private Node<T> currentNode;
        private Node<T> previous;

        /**
         * @param currentNode
         */
        public ListIterator() {
            super();
            this.currentNode = (Node<T>) head;
            this.previous = null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (currentNode != null && currentNode.next != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            if ( previous == null )
            {
                previous = currentNode;
                return previous.data;
            }
            T node = currentNode.data;
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
            return currentNode.data;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    // Same as using struct in C
    private static class Node<T> {
        private T data;
        private Node<T> next;

        /**
         * @param data
         * @param next
         */
        public Node(T data, Node<T> next) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }

        /**
         * @param next
         */
        public Node(Node<T> next) {
            super();
            this.data = null;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add("aaaa");
        list.add("bbbb");
        list.addFirst("cccc");
        list.add("dddd");
        list.add("eeee");
        list.add("ffff");
        for ( String s : list ) // same thing as using an iterator
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

<sub>This is the entirety of the class. This should fix the functionality for you, but if you spot any unsatisfactory changes (e.g. changing the `head` to initially be `null` instead of a node with null data), let me know...</sub>

Comment: Thanks Chris for pointing out to point the initial head to null.

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler solution is to just modify your `ListIterator#hasNext()` implementation as

```
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if (currentNode != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The reason your last element isn't getting covered by your `ListIterator` is that it will always return `false` for `currentNode.next != null` because it's at the end.

Removing this condition doesn't break your iterator implementation. With the above changes, when your `ListIterator` is at the last element, `hasNext()` returns `true` now. The subsequent `next()` call returns the `currentNode.data` and points the `ListIterator` to `null` which then breaks the iteration loop as required.

So basically, your `ListIterator#next()` implementation was just fine.

Comment: When I run the program with just this change, there's still an extra null printed out, meaning the last element not being printed wasn't the only issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply keep track of Head and Tail as two separate fields and, when you need to add a new node, set Tail.next to your new node and then set Tail to the new node?  Iterating through the entire list every time you want to add something is terribly inefficient.

Also, to directly answer your question, your iterator is broken.  Take a look at what your `next()` method is doing.  Is it, in fact, returning the next Node?